# Is solo play meant to use just 3 heroes?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

While I'll allow for the possibility that I'm just no good at the game, first I need to make sure I'm not just doing something wrong.

Having tried 7-8 times, I have not been able to even come close to winning the first quest in the Core Set as a solo player. Most of my games I'm not able to get a single advancement token on the first stage. Playing as a single player with just three heroes, the numbers seem stacked against me to be able to effectively quest and still attack and defend that round. The enemies pile up, or the threat tracker gets to 50 after a few rounds of holding the monsters back, or I have no choice but to take undefended damage and lose my heroes. I'm all good with having a challenging game, but for a quest with a difficulty level 1, explicitly described as an "introductory scenario," I have to wonder: is this meant to be played one player, with a single set of three heroes? It doesn't seem possible to generate enough willpower, attack strength, or resources. The rulebook doesn't address single player mode at all, so if not, what are the official solo play rules?

**Update:** Upon further research and playing, I think I can safely attribute most of my failures to an underestimation of the importance of traveling to and exploring locations. While still not a total breeze, it made threat level much more manageable.

Answer (score 5):

You are supposed to play as a single player, i.e. with 3 Heroes one your side and drawing a *single* card from the encounter deck each turn.

The pre-constructed decks in the game are unfortunately not the best and at the same time, the game is quite hard (even the beginner scenarios). Both combined can lead to your frustrating experience.

Here is a link to a guide for solo players who are new to the game: 
https://boardgamegeek.com/blogpost/16397/guide-new-lotrlcg-solo-players 
This should help you in getting started and get over the steep learning curve, which this game definitely has.

Answer (score 0):

Lord of the Ring LCG is hard as hell when played solo. The first few times I was close to desperation. :-)

Most scenarios are definitely easier when played with 2 hero-parties instead of only 1, but this actually is not the way a solo-play is supposed to be and it can get difficult to handle anyway.

Now what I can tell you: the 4 base sets are not equally strong. In the core-scenarios, it's much easier to win with "lore" than with "tactics" or "leadership". So I suggest to start with Lore and the first quest.

What I also found helpful was the "Watch it played"-playthrough on Youtube. It's very well done.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80gFPirxZA0&list=PL7691E24FD7613341

Comment: I agree that it's difficult to succeed with the **tactics** starter deck because it has few cards for questing. I played about 6 games until I finally succeeded - it's possible. However I found the **leadership** deck easy to win with.